# Sorted dicts lists manual changing

Tags: django, django-templates

In my views I have a dict list such as

```
data = [{'name': 'Abe', 'seq': [4, 3]}, {'name': 'All names', 'seq': [9, 8]}, {'name': 'Mike', 'seq': [11, 2]}]
```

In my template I sorted them with:

```
{{ data|dictsort:"name" }}
```

I'd like to have `{'name': 'All names', 'seq': [9, 8]}` in the top of the list and keep the other sorted data items. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the sorting in the view, using a custom key function.

```
data.sort(key=lambda d: '0' if d['name'] == 'All names' else d['name'])
```